# Not able to use objective-C class in swift unit tests

Tags: objective-c, swift, xctest, bridging-header

I want to use objective C class in my swift tests.

- My project is initially set up in objective c.
- I have bridging header set up already working for my project.
- I have import statement already in place in bridging header for the file, which I want to use in tests.
- Search paths for test target are also set to same bridging header, although I've tried using separate bridging headers also.
- I use cocoa pods so have a xcworkspace file.
- Pod file has inherit search path included for tests, though I am not using pod frameworks in tests.

I get 'Use of undeclared type 'SySearchProductRequest'' error while trying to use the class. SySearchProductRequest is the objc class I want to use.

I am using @testable import Mymodulename to import my module which has this class, in tests.

I am stuck with an approach of writing objc test cases, which I don't want to do. Is there a way or is there something I am doing wrong or missing to make this work.

Comment: http://codesheriff.blogspot.com/2015/05/importing-swift-code-from-objective-c.html doesn't work either.

Comment: I tried adding $CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR/MyProject.build/DerivedSources in my test target to include Derived sources in my HEADER SEARCH PATHS, It seems to have solved the issue although I was trying multiple things so not sure about this.

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't work for me because none of the Objective-C header files are copied to $CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR/MyProject.build/DerivedSources.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if your class is added to Test Targets in Target Membership in File Inspector [Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cb2G.png). and Then Build the project again . Hope It removes the error .

Comment: Hey @Saurabh I use testable import to resolve paths, so this step is not needed. Thanks

Comment: Saurabh, I strongly discourage adding production code to test targets. While "it works," it's not correct.

Comment: OK @Jon Reid . I will think about it and try to find better solution for the problem. Thanks .

Comment: @JonReid Can you please expand on you discouraging of adding production code to test target ? How are you going to test your production code unless it is added to the test target ?

Comment: @Petar When set up correctly, the test target links against the production code target. Except for things declared private, everything is accessible with @ testable import.